# Store User Values in Python Game Using Class Methods

Tags: python

Python beginner here--working on a Battleship project for a class. My program will loop through the first player to place their ships.  The grid does successfully print the visual ships on the board, but once i get to player two, the ships are overlapping with player one. (also note there is some validation work that still needs to be done).

I think the issue is that maybe I'm storing both coordinates for each player in the same list.  So my question is how do I store the values for each player so that I can get the board to print ships only applicable to each player?

**Here are my classes:**

```
BOARD_SIZE = 10

class Ship:

    def __init__(self, ship_name, size, coords, player, direction):
        self.ship_name = ship_name
        self.size = size
        self.player = player
        self.coords = coords
        self.direction = direction


class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = []
        self.guesses = []

    board = [['O']*BOARD_SIZE for _ in range(BOARD_SIZE)]

    def add_ship(self, name, size, player, coords, direction):
        for coord in coords:
            # convert string like "a1" to x,y coordinates
            y = ord(coord[0])-ord('a')
            x = int(coord[1:])-1
            # update the board at this position
            self.board = board[x][y]
        print("   " + " ".join([chr(c) for c in range(ord('A'), ord('A') + BOARD_SIZE)]))
        row_num = 1
        for row in board:
            print(str(row_num).rjust(2) + " " + (" ".join(row)))
            row_num += 1
        self.board.append(Ship(coords,player,name,size,direction))

    def print_board_heading(self):
        print("   " + " ".join([chr(c) for c in range(ord('A'), ord('A') + BOARD_SIZE)]))

    def print_board(self):
        board = [['O']*BOARD_SIZE for _ in range(BOARD_SIZE)]
        print_board_heading()
        row_num = 1
        for row in board:
            print(str(row_num).rjust(2) + " " + (" ".join(row)))
            row_num += 1

    def print_updated_board(coords, direction, board, player):
        for coord in coords:
            # convert string like "a1" to x,y coordinates
            y = ord(coord[0])-ord('a')
            x = int(coord[1:])-1
            # update the board at this position
            board[x][y] = '|' if direction == 'v' else '-'
        print("   " + " ".join([chr(c) for c in range(ord('A'), ord('A') + BOARD_SIZE)]))
        row_num = 1
        for row in board:
            print(str(row_num).rjust(2) + " " + (" ".join(row)))
            row_num += 1


class Player():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.board = Board()
        self.ships = []
        self.guesses = []
```

**And the battleship game file:**

```
from ship import Ship, Player, Board

SHIP_INFO = [
    ("Aircraft Carrier", 5),
    ("Battleship", 4),
    ("Submarine", 3),
    ("Cruiser", 3),
    ("Patrol Boat", 2)
]

BOARD_SIZE = 10

VERTICAL_SHIP = '|'
HORIZONTAL_SHIP = '-'
EMPTY = 'O'
MISS = '.'
HIT = '*'
SUNK = '#'

board = [['O']*BOARD_SIZE for _ in range(BOARD_SIZE)]

def print_board_heading():
    print("   " + " ".join([chr(c) for c in range(ord('A'), ord('A') + BOARD_SIZE)]))


def print_board():
    board = [['O']*BOARD_SIZE for _ in range(BOARD_SIZE)]
    print_board_heading()
    row_num = 1
    for row in board:
        print(str(row_num).rjust(2) + " " + (" ".join(row)))
        row_num += 1

def print_updated_board(coords, direction,board):
    # create an empty board
    # board = [['O']*BOARD_SIZE for _ in range(BOARD_SIZE)]
    # at each coordinate, draw a ship

    for coord in coords:
        # convert string like "a1" to x,y coordinates
        y = ord(coord[0])-ord('a')
        x = int(coord[1:])-1
        # update the board at this position
        board[x][y] = '|' if direction == 'v' else '-'
    print_board_heading()
    row_num = 1
    for row in board:
        print(str(row_num).rjust(2) + " " + (" ".join(row)))
        row_num += 1


def clear_screen():
    print("\033c", end="")


def get_coordinates(ship):
    while True:
        print("\n")
        coordinate = input("Where do you want the " + ship + "(example: A1)?: ")
        coords_strip = coordinate.strip()
        coords_lower = coords_strip.lower()
        x = coords_lower[0]
        y = coords_lower[1:]

        if (len(x)+len(y)) in range(2,4):
            if x not in 'abcdefghij' or y not in '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10':
                print("Oops!  That was not a valid entry.  Try again...")
                continue

            else:
                return x, y

        else:
            if len(coords_lower) < 2 or len(coords_lower) > 3:
                print("Oops!  That's too not the right amount of characters. Please try again...")
                continue


def get_direction():
    while True:
        dir = input("[H]orizontal or [V]ertical?: ")
        dir_strip = dir.strip()
        direction = dir_strip.lower()

        if direction not in 'hv':
            print("Oops!  That was not a valid entry.  Try again...")
            continue

        else:
            return direction


def create_ship_coordinates(x, y, size, direction):
    ship_col = ord(x)
    ship_row = int(y)
    if direction == 'v':
        # ship runs vertically DOWN from coordinate
        coords = [chr(ship_col) + str(r) for r in range(ship_row, ship_row + size)]
        return coords
    else:
        # ship runs horizontally RIGHT from coordinate
        coords = [chr(col) + str(ship_row) for col in range(ship_col, ship_col + size)]
        return coords


def place_user_ships(player):
    ships = []
    print_board()
    print("\n")
    print("Let's go " + player + " !")
    for ship, size in SHIP_INFO:

        while True:
            # ask for starting coordinate
            x, y = get_coordinates(ship)
            # ask for vertical or horizontal direction
            direction = get_direction()
            # create the coordinates for the ship placement
            coords = create_ship_coordinates(x, y, size, direction)
            # validate the
            # new_ship = Board().add_ship(ship, size, coords, direction, player)
            # update = Board.print_updated_board(coords,direction,board,player)
            break
        # create ship from data
        # add the ship from above to a player list
        # player = Player(board)
        # place the ship on the game board
        # print out the board to reflect the shp placement
    clear_screen()
    print("\n")
    input("All ships placed for {}. Please hit ENTER to continue....".format(player))

player1 = input("What's Player 1's Name? ")
player2 = input("What's Player 2's Name? ")

# define player one's fleet
place_user_ships(player1)
place_user_ships(player2)
```

Comment: Fair enough is there a way for me to just move it over there?

Comment: After looking through your question again, I actually don't think it's fully on-topic for either SO or Code Review. For SO, you should ask just **one** question that is related to a specific programming problem. The questions in your bullet-points are either too broad, or primarily opinion-based. For Code-Review, you should only ask for feedback on a *fully working program*, and also avoid generic questions about best practices.

Comment: Changed question hope that is easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, in battleship there are really four boards. One is managed by each player with their shots at the enemy, and the other is the player's own ships and incoming shots from the enemy.

The "shot" process is one of notifying the enemy where the shot was taken, the enemy responding with "hit" or "miss", and recording the result on the local player's outgoing-shots board.

The "notification" process is one of receiving a location where an enemy shot was made, looking up the result on the local-ships board, returning "hit" or "miss", and updating the local ships board to indicate the enemy shot.

So you have a Player, with a pair of Boards. You might also have a Game class to marry the two players.

Inputting the ships is going to depend a lot on your actual user interface. Are you doing graphics with a mouse? Are you doing text with a mouse? Text with arrow keys via `curses` or some such? Simple coordinate inputs?

If you're doing coordinates, you probably want something simple, like x,y,{up,down,left,right} to eliminate having to position every block of the ship.

Again, there is a Board method here - placing a ship. The board can enforce whatever rules you have about placement (ex: can two ships be directly adjacent? Or must there be a one-space gap between?) and reject the inappropriate attempts.

If you put all the wisdom in your Board class, then the Player classes can be simple, with just links to the boards. And the game can manage the players in turn:

```
def play(self):
    p1 = self.player[0]
    p2 = self.player[1]

    try:
        while True:
            self.attack(p1, p2)
            self.attack(p2, p1)

    except Victory v:
        print("The winner is", v.player.name)
```

I notice you doing things like `player1 = input("What is player 1's name?")`. This is something that should be pushed into the player classes.

Try to design from the top down: game, player, board. And try following the rule, "Tell, don't ask." That is, if something needs to be done, you *tell* a class to do it, instead of *asking* the class for data and doing it yourself.

Instead of this:

```
move = player1.get_move()
if valid_move(move):
    ...
```

Do this:

```
player1.make_move()
```

And push the logic downwards. Eventually, you get to the place where the knowledge "should be". The player "should" make moves. The board "should" know what is a valid move or not. And every method "should" be given enough data to do its job. ;-)

Comment: thanks Austin--some good advice here, thanks for taking the time to explain it to me.